# GitHub - Find the pull request associated with a commit

Tags: git, github

I'm trying to find a past pull request to see which comments / actions were made on a particular issue.

I know the file and the change, so I can get to the commit that introduced it by looking at the blame view. However I can't find a way to look at the pull request that pushed that commit to the branch for the first time.

Is there a way to do this? Or do I have to go on a trip down memory lane and manually browse through past pull requests?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can filter your pull requests based on the commit SHA - see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/searching-for-information-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-commit-sha)

> If you know the specific SHA hash of a commit, you can use it to search for pull requests that contain that SHA. Note that the SHA syntax must be at least seven characters.

> For example:

> **e1109ab**
> Matches pull requests with a commit SHA that starts with `e1109ab`.

> **0eff326d6213c is:merged**
> Matches merged pull requests with a commit SHA that starts with `0eff326d6213c`.

Comment: when I searched a commit hash like you mentioned, [https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=type%3Apr+209775e&type=Issues] it provide me two Pull request both has merged the same commit to the master. In such kind of scenario what we should select as the Pull request that merged the relevant commit

Answer (score 4):

GitHub has recently added an easier way to do this to their GraphQL API: https://developer.github.com/v4/changelog/2019-03-08-schema-changes/.

Here's an example query which demonstrates how to fetch associated pull requests of the five latest commits on the master branch:

```
{
  repository(name: "react", owner: "facebook") {
    ref(qualifiedName: "master") {
      target {
        ... on Commit {
          id
          history(first: 5) {
            nodes {
              id
              associatedPullRequests(first: 10) {
                edges {
                  node {
                    title
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you don't know the head org and head branch of the PR.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can navigate to the URL `https://github.com/search?q=[commit-id]&type=pullrequests`.

This is documented [here](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests#search-by-commit-sha).

Answer (score 2):

The [refined-github browser extension](https://github.com/refined-github/refined-github) adds a link to the PR on commits, even on a fork. (Among many other features). It is available in Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Answer (score 2):

The github-cli tool can do this easily.

```
gh pr list --search "${SHA}" --state merged
```

for more info: https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list