# How to retrieve associated pull requests for a specific commit hash with GitHub's GraphQL API?

Tags: python, github, graphql, github-api, pull-request

I have a list of commit hashes for a particular GitHub repository. For each commit hash, I want to see if it appears (or not) in a pull request – and also see other information about the pull request (e.g., if it is closed/open, if it is merged or not, etc.). I need to automate the process, so I'm trying to use GitHub's APIs.

My initial attempt was to use the ["Search" feature](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28#search-issues-and-pull-requests) offered by GitHub's REST API, but unfortunately, GitHub limits its Search feature to only "30 requests per minute for all search endpoints" (https://docs.github.com/en/rest/search?apiVersion=2022-11-28#rate-limit). As such, I now have to use GitHub's [GraphQL API](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/guides/introduction-to-graphql), which has a limit of 5,000 requests per hour (if you are using an authentication token, which I am).

I did quite a bit of searching online, but there doesn't seem to be any kind of documentation or help at all for this particular case. The closest links I found were these:

- [GitHub - Find the pull request associated with a commit](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35915261)
- https://gist.github.com/mccutchen/9a0530a440470b4dee57c53284a18b52
- https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/24679

What I have so far is the following GraphQL query:

```
query ($repoOwner: String!, $repoName: String!, $sha: String!) {
  repository(name: $repoName, owner: $repoOwner) {
    commit: object(expression: $sha) {
      ... on Commit {
        commitUrl
        associatedPullRequests(first: 10) {
          edges {
            node {
              title
              number
              body
              state
              mergedAt
              closedAt
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

with the following variables:

```
{
  "repoOwner": "<REPOSITORY_OWNER>",
  "repoName": "<REPOSITORY_NAME>",
  "sha": "<COMMIT_HASH>"
}
```

The **issue** is that that query only returns the associated pull request for **MERGED** pull requests only. For example, if we look at this pull request for numpy (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/23753/commits), we can see that it is *merged*, and it has one associated commit (with hash `725777de1b8dea22edf9421a47ccf0807b477ae7`). Specifying that hash along with the repo name and owner in my GraphQL query above correctly returns the corresponding pull request (`#23753`). However, here is a pull request that is **not** merged (https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/23751/commits). It has 1 commit (`ab2bd9d9b997a315d2c4e3175ba03ab3a435543d`), just like the other pull request. But this time, when we pass that commit in the GraphQL query above, the list of associated pull requests that the query returns is *empty*, despite that commit hash clearly being associated with a pull request.

What's weird is that when I use the Search function in the REST API:

```
https://api.github.com/search/issues?q=repo:numpy/numpy+type:pr+sha:ab2bd9d9b997a315d2c4e3175ba03ab3a435543d
```

it correctly returns the associated pull request (`#23751`), along with all its other information (its title, when it was closed, etc.).

My question is, thus: **For a given commit hash, how can I use the GraphQL API to look up the associated pull request, *even if* the pull request is not in the "merged" state?**